# Como recuperar texto de um widget do tkinter, criado com o gerador de GUIs PAGE?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estou tentando criar uma interface em que o usuario possa digitar um texto e salvar esse texto em um documento txt. Para facilitar o processo, usei um gerador de GUIs chamado PAGE, que usa o package TKinter, que já vem com o Python.
O codigo que a PAGE gerou foi o seguinte:

```
class New_Toplevel:
    def __init__(self, top=None): 
        self.Text1 = Text(top)
        self.Text1.place(relx=0.017, rely=0.133, relheight=0.831, 
                              relwidth=0.94)
        self.Text1.configure(background="white")
        self.Text1.configure(font="TkTextFont")
        self.Text1.configure(foreground="black")
        self.Text1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Text1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Text1.configure(insertbackground="black")
        self.Text1.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")
        self.Text1.configure(selectforeground="black")
        self.Text1.configure(width=564)
        self.Text1.configure(wrap=WORD)
```

O problema é que não consigo recuperar o texto da janela. Tentei usar o get() method, mas ele não retorna nada, e não consigo chamar o objeto Text1 de fora da classe, para poder usar a solução que deram nesse post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824163/how-to-get-the-input-from-the-tkinter-text-box-widget

Alguma solução?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua pergunta está incompleta, faltou colocar o código onde você tenta acessar o `self.Text1` e o erro que está gerando.

Você diz que o método `get()` não retorna nada, mas isso não é possível... Ele **sempre retorna alguma coisa**, ou uma string, ou erro. É uma informação falsa que colocou na pergunta.

Para pegar o texto digitado o comando é:

```
texto_digitado = self.Text1.get(1.0, END)
```

Segue abaixo um exemplo completo que você pode executar, só completei o seu código com o que faltava pra ele funcionar de forma mínima:

[image: imagem da tela]

```
from tkinter import Tk, Text, Button, WORD, END, messagebox


class New_Toplevel:
    def __init__(self, top=None): 
        Button(top, text='OK', command=self.clicou).pack()
        self.Text1 = Text(top)
        self.Text1.place(relx=0.017, rely=0.133, relheight=0.831, 
                              relwidth=0.94)
        self.Text1.configure(background="white")
        self.Text1.configure(font="TkTextFont")
        self.Text1.configure(foreground="black")
        self.Text1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Text1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Text1.configure(insertbackground="black")
        self.Text1.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")
        self.Text1.configure(selectforeground="black")
        self.Text1.configure(width=564)
        self.Text1.configure(wrap=WORD)

    def clicou(self):
        texto = self.Text1.get(1.0, END)
        with open('arquivo.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(texto)
        messagebox.showinfo(title='Conteúdo', message='O texto contém: ' + texto)

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')    
t = New_Toplevel(root)
root.mainloop()
```